# What's best way to know if server was accessed by HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: php, apache, https, apache2

With Apache and PHP, what's the best way to know it, and to force using HTTPS?

I searched in phpinFO() for $_SERVER variables and found nothing that could help.

Edit: thanks for answers and suggestions! I can't force it on server level because it's only for login page.

Comment: To force it? mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is non-empty if HTTPS was used. But you'd be better off doing the HTTPS enforcement at the webserver level, e.g.

```
<virtualhost example.com:80>
   redirect permanent https://example.com
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost example.com:443>
   blah blah blah
</virtualhost>
```

Comment: If it's important enough, I just set up apache to serve the content at https, and not at http at all.

Comment: but you'd still need a redirect on non-https links, because far too many people will miss that `s` in https when entering it.

Comment: Right, if it's the landing page.  In that case I would put a non-secure version of the page there (with a login button or whatever that redirects to https).  That's just me though, on my poor little home server with a dozen virtual hosts, where each https has to use a different port.  The average user would NEVER type in the port part right.  :-)  Still, your advice is nice and more concise.

Answer (score 2):

In an .htaccess file, add the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://YOUR_URL/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, consider adding the HSTS HTTP header. This tells browsers to not even try to visit the HTTP version, and to go directly to HTTPS. This prevents a possible man-in-the middle attack, where your redirect could be intercepted.

(Provided the user has visited the site before, or your website is added to the builtin HSTS list.)

See http://dev.chromium.org/sts for how to get added to the builtin list, and an example of what the header looks like.

Answer (score 2):

The only right answer is because you configured your server to behave that way.

If you don't know, with absolute confidence, by the time a request is sent to PHP whether it has been sent via HTTP or HTTPS then your system is not secure.